# Generic parameters for a constructor in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, constructor

Consider the following contrived Java example:

```
public class Example {

    private final Object value;
    private final List<?> aListOfTheseThings;

    public <T> Example(final T t, final List<T> aListOfTheseThings) {
        this.value = t;
        this.aListOfTheseThings = aListOfTheseThings;
    }

}
```

What I care about in this Example:

1. `Example` is not parameterized
2. The constructor *is* paremeterized and makes sure that whatever you pass in, the list is parameterized in the same type of `t`

(This is a contrived example, I do not really care about `(2)` but I really do care about having a type parameter there which is not mentioned in the definition of the class).

Now in Scala I tried the following:

```
class Example private[this](
  private val value: AnyRef,
  private val aListOfTheseThings: List[_]) {

  def this[T](t: T, aListOfTheseThings: List[T]) {
    this(t, aListOfTheseThings)
  }
}
```

...but this is not possible. Apparently a type parameter is not valid in a constructor (in `this`).

Any chance of translating the above Java code into Scala?

Comment: how about an `apply[T]` factory method in the companion object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this help:

```
sealed trait Example

object Example {
  def apply[T <: AnyRef](t:T, aListOfTheseThings: List[T]): Example = 
    new ExampleImpl(t, aListOfTheseThings)

  private class ExampleImpl(
    val value: AnyRef, 
    val aListOfTheseThings: List[_]) extends Example 
}
```

This makes private constructor of class `Example`. value and `aListOfTheseThings` are not accessed via `Example` trait (unless you make it accessible)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how it would work if I now wanted to subclass like `class AnEvenMoreContrivedExample extends Example("a thing", List("some", "things"))`

Answer (score 7):

Nyavro's suggestion of a helper `apply` method is a good one. Another option that might be appropriate in some cases is subclassing:

```
trait Example {
  val value: Any
  val things: List[_]
}

class SameTypeExample[T](val value: T, val things: List[T]) extends Example
```

The advantage of subclassing is that the constraint that `value` and `things` store the same type is not lost, and can be re-discovered by pattern matching:

```
def handle(example: Example) = example match {
  case st: SameTypeExample[t] =>
    st.value :: st.things    
}
```

Subclassing is a general technique in Scala for temporarily hiding information that was present at construction time.

Comment: I like the subclassing approach, but the apply() method already solves my issue :-) That's why I accepted the other Nyavro's answer.